# Is there a standard way to test scripts/executables in Jenkins?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, continuous-integration, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have a project that contains a library of Python and Scala packages, as well as Bourne, Python and Perl executable scripts.  Although the library has good test coverage, we don't have any tests on the scripts.

The current testing environment uses Jenkins, Python, virtualenv, nose, Scala, and sbt.

Is there a standard/common way to incorporate testing of scripts in Jenkins?

---

Edit: I'm hoping for something simple like Python's unittest for shell scripts, like this:

```
assertEquals expected.txt commandline
assertError commandline --bogus
assertStatus 11 commandline baddata.in
```

Comment: Any context about these scripts?  Are they environmentally sensitive? (i.e., make HTTP requests to servers, need files in certain locations, etc).

Comment: @sethcall Good question. There are many scripts which variously depend on test data, a couple of databases, http requests, and another in-house project (currently referenced by an environment variable). We  can create an environment sufficient for these tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at shunit2: https://github.com/kward/shunit2

It allows you to write testable shell scripts in Bourne, bash or ksh scripts.

Not sure how you can integrate it into what you're describing, but it generates output similar to other unit test suites.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I didn't know about that at the time I asked, but I found it via the link Wikipedia link that malenkiy_scot provided. shunit2 is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks to @Reece for the update to this answer!

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how 'standard' this is, but if you truly practice TDD your scripts also should be developed with TDD. How you connect your TDD tests with Jenkins then depends on the TDD framework you are using: you can generate JUnit reports for example, that Jenkins can read, or  your tests can simply return failed status, etc.

Comment: This is exactly the question. I'd like to use Jenkins to enable TDD for scripts. For languages, there are frameworks. Is there a framework for the command line?

Comment: I use very few command-line scripts (relying mostly on ANT ant Python), but for all it's worth [here's what Wikipedia says about it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#Shell).

Comment: Thanks @malenkiy_scot... the Wikipedia page provides a good summary. Hard to believe that page didn't turn up in my many searches.

Answer (score 0):

If your script requires another project, then my inclination is to make a new jenkins project, say 'system-qa'.

This would be a downstream project of the python project, and have a dependency on the python project and the in-house project.

If you were using dependency resolution/publishing technology, say [apache ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/)  http://ant.apache.org/ivy/, and if these existing projects were to publish a packaged version of their code (as simple as a .tar.gz, perhaps), then system-qa project could then declare dependencies (again, using ivy) for both the python package and the in-house project package, download it using ivy, extract/install it, run tests, and exit.

So in summary, the system-qa project's build script is responsible for retrieving dependencies, running tests against those dependencies, and then perhaps publishing a standardized output test format like junit xml (but at a minimum returning 0 or non-0 to clue Jenkins in on how the built went).

I think this is a technically correct solution, but also a lot of work.  Judgement call required if it's worth it.

Comment: Clarification about using apache ivy for the movement of project artifacts between projects.  If you only have one build drone and one active version of these projects, then you can make simplifying assumptions; like just setting that environment variable you mentioned to /home/jenkinsbuild/workspace/inhouse-project, instead of using ivy.